# Drawing application undo button

Tags: javascript, windows, html, canvas, drawing

i have problem with undo button for my drawing application

```
<input id="undo" type="image" src="images/undo.ico" onclick="cUndo()" width="25" height="25">
```

```
var cPushArray = new Array();
var cStep = -1;
var ctx;
// ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");

function cPush() {
    cStep++;
    if (cStep < cPushArray.length) { cPushArray.length = cStep; }
    cPushArray.push(document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL());
}
function cUndo() {
    if (cStep > 0) {
        cStep--;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
        canvasPic.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0); }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.Please help

Comment: Just add comments in before each line/function to explain what it's doing. Some bugs should disappear already.

Comment: You wont be able to use the `drawImage` method if `ctx` isn't defined

Comment: @GameAlchemist How will adding comments make the bugs disappear?

Comment: @epascarello: because you see that what you intend to do is not what you actually do.

Answer (score 1):

First remark : As @markE underlines, saving with DataURL has a high memory cost. You might consider saving the draw commands + their arguments within an array instead.
Seek for tuts/Stack Overflow post on the topic, out of a few posts you should get some nice ideas.

Anyway, you can go with the dataURL solution in a first time to get your application working (with a limit of 20 undos or like to avoid memory explosion), then you can later improve the undo to reach a higher limit.
I updated my code to handle such a stack limit.

For your issue : onload should be hooked prior to setting the src, but anyway with a DataURL you are not async : the image is built at once, so no need to hook unload.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var historic = [];
var maxHistoricLength = 20; // might be more or less, depending on canvas size...

function saveForUndo() {
    historic.push(canvas.toDataURL());
    if (historic.length === maxHistoricLength +1) historic.shift(); 
}

function canUndo() {
  return (historic.length !== 0 );
}

function undo() {
    if (!canUndo()) return;
    var lastDataURL = historic.pop();
    var tmpImage = new Image();
    tmpImage.src = lastDataURL;
    ctx.drawImage(tmpImage, 0, 0); 
}
```

Comment: While your answer does help the questioner with a problem in their current design, you might let the questioner know that saving the canvas incrementally with .toDataURL is very resource intensive--probably not a good design except in edge cases.

Comment: @markE : I thought this would have been one of the few next steps, but yes, why not mentioning this now ? : i updated my post, thanks.